# list style align error

Tags: html, css

[image]

First elements of the list tend to float to the right for some reason.All bullets should be at the start, and too the left of all text.

```css
.bullet-wrap {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.five {
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}
.bullet-wrap {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="bullet-wrap">
  <div class="bullet-point">
    <span>1</span>Reduce Carbon Footprint
  </div>
  <ul class="bullet-list">
    <li class="five">Using a minimum of 10% recycled pre-consumer cellular PVC scrap By:</li>
    <li class="five">Harvesting heat from equipment to heat plant and office;</li>
    <li class="five">Combining customer orders to maximize shipments.</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `.bullet-wrap` is floated left, which would bring the first item in the list to the top. Try putting a `clear: both;` rule on `.bullet-list`. In order to get the bullets aligned, you could try to use `list-style-position: inside;` as a rule on your `li`'s.

Comment: thanks that did it. I do appreciate the help.

Comment: Great! I added the comment as an answer, would you mind to accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `.bullet-wrap` is floated left, which would bring the first item in the list to the top.

Try putting a `clear: both;` rule on `.bullet-list`.

In order to get the bullets aligned, you could try to use `list-style-position: inside;` as a rule on your li's.